# Нотификации каждую минуту

Tags: java, android

Хочу создавать notification каждую минуту,взял код с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234799/how-to-show-android-notification-after-every-48hours
Программа запускается,но ничего не создается.Что я делаю не так?
ShowNotification:

```
public class ShowNotification extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "ShowNotification";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
                = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setContentTitle("New SMS " + System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText("Hello")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_email_white_24dp)
                .setTicker("ticker message")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        Log.i(TAG, "Notification created");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowNotification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(contentIntent);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                , 1000*60, contentIntent);
```

Comment: Вы сервис в манифесте прописали?

Comment: Если Вам нужно что то делать именно каждую минуту, то можете создать [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) и подписать его на событие [Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK). Оно как раз каждую минуту возникает.

Comment: AlarmManager будет работать(если вы repeat время правильно поставите), но здесь лучше использовать Handler. Хотя на данный момент невозможно ответить однозначно, так не ясно какую задачу вы преследуете.